# How can I rotate a circle clockwise on processing?

Tags: animation, rotation, processing

I would like to make my slow circle (the green one) rotate clockwise but I am not quite sure how. I would like it to center it and slowly turn, distance from the center could be 200 or 150.

```
float slow_circle_x = 0;
float fast_circle_x = 0;

void setup() {
  size(400,400); 
  noStroke();
}

void draw() {
  background(#1BB1F5);
  
  float slow_circle_size = 50;
  
// what do you think this next line does?
  if(random(10) > 9) {
    slow_circle_size = 60;
  }  
    if  (random(10) < 5) {
      slow_circle_size = 30;
  } else{
    slow_circle_size = 40; }
  
  fill(#C1FF3E);
  ellipse(slow_circle_x,50, slow_circle_size, slow_circle_size);
  slow_circle_x = slow_circle_x + 1;

  fill(#FF4800);
  ellipse(fast_circle_x,50, 50, 50);
  fast_circle_x = fast_circle_x + 5;

  
  if(slow_circle_x > 400) {
    slow_circle_x = 0;
  }
  if(fast_circle_x > 400) {
    fast_circle_x = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: If a flat coloured circle rotates around it's own axis you won't be able to observe the rotation. Can you please clarify: which point / object does the green circle rotates around ? (is it the orange circle for example ? if so what distance will the green circle "orbit" around the orange circle and how fast would it rotate ?) (you mention distance from centre of 200 or 150, but it's unclear (at least to me) the centre of what you mean exactly)

Comment: Do you mean orbital rotation? Self-axis rotation? You need to clarify what time of movement you are trying to accomplish. Your code clearly does not represent a bare minimum approximation to your goal. It only move two circles from left to right while the slow circle's size stutters (thanks to the random logic that you implemented